# What is the purpose of setting serveroutput in oracle?

Tags: oracle

Could someone let me know what is the purpose of using set serveroutput on/off in oracle?

I ran the below query to see what it is doing. However I need to know much about serveroutput. Kindly help me

```
 set serveroutput on;
     select * from tab;
    select * from tab;
     select * from tab;
     set serveroutput off;
```

Comment: set serveroutput [on|off] is used to enable or disable the output made by the DBMS_OUTPUT package, for example in sql*Plus; in your example, it has no effect.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas :) Any weblinks which will give more information would be much beneficial. However Now I understood the purpose of set serveroutput. Thanks a lot

Comment: Oracle 11.2 SQLPlus Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#sthref2163

Answer (score 4):

`set serveroutput on` executed in SQL Plus executes behind the scenes:

```
dbms_output.enable(buffer_size => NULL);
```

`set serveroutput off` executes:

```
dbms_output.disable;
```